# Замыкания в языке Python

Tags: python, замыкания

начал разбираться в теме замыкания в языке Python, и выполнил такое вот *задание*: используя замыкания функций, объявите внутреннюю функцию, которая преобразует строку
из списка целых чисел, записанных через пробел, либо в список, либо в кортеж. Тип
коллекции определяется параметром type внешней функции. Если `type = 'list'` , то
используется список, иначе – кортеж. Далее, на вход программы поступает две строки:
первая – это значение для параметра type; вторая – список целых чисел, записанных через пробел. С помощью реализованного замыкания преобразовать эту строку в
соответствующую коллекцию. Результат работы замыкания выведите на экран.
Сам код:

```
def func(type: str):
    def inner(value):
        gen = (e for e in value.split())
        if type == 'list':
            return list(gen)
        return tuple(gen)

    return inner


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(func('list')('1 2 3 4'))
    print(func('tuple')('1 2 3 4 5'))
```

Хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли понял тему и есть ли ошибки в коде. Спасибо.

Comment: Как минимум, в задании сказано использовать строку `'list'`, но в вашем коде такой строки нигде нет

Comment: Я, пожалуй, подпишусь на этот вопрос. Сначала улыбнуло словосочетание "замыкание в Python",  а потом я как загуглил =) Где то я это пропустил

Comment: При такой передаче параметра как у вас можно было бы один `return` делать `return t(map(int, ...`, но в задаче параметр - это строка.

Comment: @andreymal , получается мне надо исправить так: `def func(type: str)`?

Comment: @vladimir15 даже если вы так напишете, класс `list` не превратится от этого в строку магическим образом

Comment: @andreymal можете сказать, правильно ли исправил?

Answer (score 1):

ваш код работает правильно, особо добавить нечего, просто предложу немного другой вариант исполнения:

```
def func(type_: str):
    t = list if type_=='list' else tuple
    def inner(value):
        return t(value.split())
    return inner

to_list = func('list')
to_tuple = func('tuple')
to_set = func('set')  # !

print(to_list('1 2 3 4'), to_tuple('5 6 7 8'), to_set('9 10 11 11'), sep='\n')
```

результат:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
('5', '6', '7', '8')
('9', '10', '11', '11')
```